# BeautifulSoup not scraping next pages

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'www.mywebsite.com'
driver.get(url)
response = requests.get(url)
markup = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')

for _ in range(50):
    
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END) # Move the page down
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('prevnext')
    
    
    
        
    master_list = []
    for name in soup.find_all(itemprop='name'):
        data_dict = {}
        data_dict['company name'] = name.get_text(strip=True, separator = '\n')

        master_list.append(data_dict)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(master_list)
    
    print('Page scraped')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Sleeping for 2..')

    print('Is the button enabled : ' + str(element.is_enabled()))
    print('Is the button visible : ' + str(element.is_displayed()))


    element.click();
    print('Clicked Next')
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

# #     for _ in range(1):

# #         print('waiting 10')
#     driver.find_element_by_class_name('submit-btn').click()
    
    

print('Finished Scraping')
```

I Need this to run through 50 pages. It scrapes the first one, and flips through the other ones. However, at the end only the first one is scraped and added to df. Every page has 20 records. I believe my indentation is wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your variable `soup` never changes in the loop, so the same html is being searched every time.  You would have to move `markup = driver.page_source` and `soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')` to within the loop, so you can search the html from the new page each time

Comment: Thank for all ya'lls replies. However, it doesnt work for some reason. len(master_list) still 20, which is what is per page. I tried running a loop on 4 pages, however, still the first page scraped. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made a small mistake.

```
markup = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')
```

Remove this line from your code and add it to start of your for loop as you would also need to get the source every time you click because new content is loaded everytime.

Comment: Thank for all ya'lls replies. However, it doesnt work for some reason. len(master_list) still 20, which is what is per page. I tried running a loop on 4 pages, however, still the first page scraped. Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps, the content has not yet been loaded properly after the click event. Try using WebDriverWait to wait after the button is clicked for some time and try to get source.